# How to write a windows program that replaces password authentication on logon screen

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a way to replace the windows text password login.
My app should be launched automatically and ask the user a few questions, if everything is correct than the user should be allowed to be logged in.

I don't my that a text password will be submitted by my app in the background.
the environment is very similar to face recognition/finger print recognition login.

Where should i start? (:

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:
[Windows Credential Provider with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092696/windows-credential-provider-with-c-sharp)

and here: http://pgina.org/

(I have no personal experience with this ... as yet.)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible.

Different Windows versions offer different mechanisms to achieve what you want:

- in Vista and newer you have to create a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- in XP you need to create and a [GINA DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

BEWARE: it might be difficult to do this in .NET, you most probably will need to code a native solution (C/C++ for example).