# What is the C# equivalent of this C++ code (with InPtr)

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, marshalling, credential-providers

I'm implementing a **Custom Credential Provider** in **C#**. I'm using a **C++** project as example. This piece of C++ code provides an image to Windows. The way I see it **phbmp** is a pointer to the image-bitmap. The code either updates the pointer so it points to a new bitmap (read from Resource) or it loads the bitmap to the address pointed by **phbmp**. *I'm not sure if the pointer itself is changed or not*.

```
// Get the image to show in the user tile
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetBitmapValue(DWORD dwFieldID, _Outptr_result_nullonfailure_ HBITMAP *phbmp)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    *phbmp = nullptr;

    if ((SFI_TILEIMAGE == dwFieldID))
    {
        HBITMAP hbmp = LoadBitmap(HINST_THISDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TILE_IMAGE));
        if (hbmp != nullptr)
        {
            hr = S_OK;
            *phbmp = hbmp;
        }
        else
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Below is the C# equivalent I'm implementing:

```
public int GetBitmapValue(uint dwFieldID, IntPtr phbmp)
{
    if (dwFieldID == 2)
    {
        Bitmap image = Resource1.TileImage;

        ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, phbmp, bytes.Length);

        return HResultValues.S_OK;
    }

    return HResultValues.E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. Load the image from resource (this works, it has the correct length)
2. Convert the Bitmap to an array of bytes
3. Copy these bytes to the address pointed by **phbmp**

This crashes, I assume because of memory-allocation.

The parameters in this method are defined by an interface (in **CredentialProvider.Interop.dll**, which is provided by Microsoft - I think). So I'm pretty sure it's correct and **phbmp** is not an **out**-parameter.

Because it is not an out-parameter I can not change **phbmp** to let it point to my bitmap, right? I have assigned **phbmp** to **Bitmap.GetHbitmap()** and that doesn't crash but it isn't working either. I assume that the change to **phbmp** is only local in this method.

I can understand that it is not possible to alloc memory to a predefined address. It's the other way around: you alloc memory and get an pointer to it. But then this change is local again. How does this work?

Comment: An HBITMAP is an opaque bitmap handle.  You can think of a handle as a magic integer that GDI apis can use to lookup the bitmap data from a table.  An `HBITMAP*` is then a pointer to a handle.  Your C# code has no talk of handles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092696/windows-credential-provider-with-c-sharp

Comment: @Yakk, do you think that the IntPtr in C# should be an out-parameter? I think it should to match the functionality in C++. The problem is not to get a pointer to the Bitmap (I think). Maybe the way I have done that in the C#-code is incorrect but I can get that right.

Comment: @roberth `IntPtr` is a pointer to some data.  You have to write where it is pointing, but you do not change the pointer.

Comment: @Yakk, thank you for your help. So I assume there is memory available at the address the pointer points to? But how much? They  don't know the size of my image, right? And I cannot allocate memory *on* that address because why would there be space available on that address? If I just allocate memory the size of my image, I get a new pointer to that space. if I assign that pointer to IntPtr I have changed IntPtr and that will not propagate back to the calling function because it's not an out-parameter..... I don't understand how it works.

Comment: @roberth "An HBITMAP is an opaque bitmap handle. You can think of a handle as a magic integer that GDI apis can use to lookup the bitmap data from a table."  That was the very first thing I said to you.  You need to put an HBITMAP "magic integer" into the `IntPtr`, not a bitmap.  How you get that magic integer, well, I'd write C++ code myself.  But you seem to want to write C#, so you get to fight with the .net runtime and libraries to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you @Yakk, I did so with Bitmap.GetHbitmap() as this example shows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx). But because this didn't work (sorry I'm unable to say any clearer what goes wrong) I assumed I was changing the IntPtr in the local context of this function only. But with your help I now know in which direction I have to think.

Answer (score 1):

Although some people agreed that **IntPtr** should be an out-parameter (see comments in https://syfuhs.net/2017/10/15/creating-custom-windows-credential-providers-in-net/) the answer was actually:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(imageStream);  
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(phbmp, bmp.GetHbitmap());
```